# how to get rtf file using proc report

Tags: sas, rtf, proc

I need to get output in the attached form.
My code is as shown below.
I used headskip but its not reflecting in my rtf file

```
ods rtf FILE="E:\GRAPHS/demog2.rtf" ;
         OPTIONS LS=100 PS=100 NODATE CENTER NONUMBER MISSING='' FORMDLIM='*' ;
         proc report data=finalt  headskip headline center spacing=5 split=" "  nowd
         style(header)={background=white foreground=black}
        STYLE(REPORT)=[BACKGROUND=WHITE /*BORDERCOLOR=BLACK*/  ASIS=ON  CELLPADDING=1.5
                         CELLSPACING=1.0 OUTPUTWIDTH=50%  ] /*style=[frame=hsides BORDERWIDTH = 0.1pt]*/style=journal ;
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Headskip is one of the options that does not work with ODS destinations other than LISTING.

Comment: What is another option to get a headline for ods destination rtf file

Comment: headline has no affect on other ODS output but LISTING output. What do you exactly want? underline the first row or color the bottom border of first row as black?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking the way to produce "three line" table in SAS. Here are many examples you can find on the internet. The following is a very simple way:

```
option nonumber nodate;
title;
footnote;

proc template;
  define style sasuser.custom;
  parent=rtf;
  replace table from output/frame=hsides;
  replace color_list/'bgh'=white;
  end;
run;

ods rtf file="d:\test.rtf" style=custom;
proc report data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods rtf close;
```